# Laravel slow query for 30000 db row

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 32000 occurrence of transactions in my db, this query takes too long
about 10 sec or more,

how can i optimize please

```
$data = DB::table('transactions')
    ->when($merchantId, function($query) use($merchantId) {
        return $query->where('user_id', $merchantId);
    })
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [
        Carbon::now()->startOfYear(),
        Carbon::now()->endOfYear(),
    ])->when($app, function($query) use($app) {
        return $query->where('application_id', $app);
    })
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'CANCELLED')
            ->orWhere('status', 'FAILED');
    })
    ->selectRaw("count(*) as nombre, extract($period from transactions.created_at) as $period")
    ->groupBy("$period")
    ->pluck('nombre', "$period");
```

Comment: Pplease share more details, like the execution plan of that query. I would assume that this is not related to Laravel itself after all

Comment: cAn try something like. ..https://laraveldaily.com/process-big-db-table-with-chunk-method/ ... or do eagerloding where ever possible...
https://ashallendesign.co.uk/blog/6-quick-and-easy-ways-to-speed-up-your-laravel-website

Comment: Use pagination method for solving your problem

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination